# Retornar dados da tabela parametros, mesmo que resultado $consulta for 0

Tags: php, mysql

Boa noite: Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em que consiste os parâmetros todos numa tabela de parametros... Porém, no meu SQL só funciona se tiver com registros acima de 0: Segue o código

```
public function getAcompanhantes($tipo)
{
    $consulta = $this->db->query("SELECT *, p.parametro as cidade FROM cadastroperfil AS cp, parametro as p WHERE cp.verificado = '1' AND cp.codCategoria = {$tipo} AND cp.codCidade = p.idParametro")->result();

        foreach($consulta as &$valor){
            $sql =  "SELECT * FROM parametro WHERE idParametro = {$tipo}";
            $valor->Categoria = $this->db->query($sql)->row();
        }

    return $consulta;
}
```

Mesmo se eu alterar o SQL para a seguinte forma, não dá certo:

```
SELECT * FROM cadastroperfil 
LEFT JOIN parametro ON idParametro = cadastroperfil.codCategoria
WHERE cadastroperfil.codCategoria = {$tipo}
```

Notem que na $consulta, requisitei os parametros para que eu consiga saber a cidade em que a modelo está, e também os dados do perfil. E no foreach seguinte, busco os dados da categoria, pra eu saber se é homem, mulher e etc. Mas, ele só passa os parametros na segunda, se a primeira tiver registros maiores do que zero. Gostaria de ver se alguém tem alguma sugestão. 
Muito obrigado.

Comment: você precisa modelar melhor o banco de dados. O ideal é retornar todos os dados em apenas uma consulta. Ou ainda poderia criar uma view direto no banco de dados. Pensa isso.